# Making a secure login cookie

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, cookies

I've recently read one of Jeff's [articles about XSS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) and it got me thinking about how to better protect the login cookies in my home cooked authentication system.

Basically what I do now is this(note, everything is configurable and currently set to `true`):

```
     protected static string ComputeLoginHash(string passwordhash){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(passwordhash);
        if(CookieUseIP){
            sb.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
        }
        if(CookieUseBase){
            sb.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("/"));
        }
        if(CookieUseBrowserInfo){
            sb.Append(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent);
        }
        sb.Append(SiteName);
        return ComputeHash(sb.ToString());
    }
```

(note that passwordhash is made out of password, unique salt, and username).

Ok, so one of the questionable things I do is use the `UserAgent` string. Is there harm in doing this? Or browsers which will change their UserAgent string under normal operation(as in, without being updated)? My goal is basically for if an attacker gets a login cookie, for them to not be able to do anything with it. Would this help meet my goal or is it just overly cumbersome for the user? At the moment, the only info I store in the cookie plain text is the username.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost you should never write your own session handler.  You are reinventing the wheel and it will be less secure.

If `ComputeLoginHash()` is producing a cookie value then you a **big problem** on your hands.     An attacker can obtain the username/password hash from the database and then build a cookie value by passing it to a hash function.   This would allow an attacker to login without the need to cracking a password.  Effectively you are completely removing the protection provided by hashing passwords.

A cookie value must always be a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce),  this value must expire (less than a day is good.).  For added security enable [http-only cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which helps thwart xss. Also set the [sts-header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to enforce https and in turn take care of OWASP A9.  Also,don't forget about [session riding](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).   Also there is absolutely no point in checking the user-agent because this is an attacker controlled variable.

Comment: I currently do not have HTTPS on my site, and I do have http-only enabled. And also, is there anyway to be secure **without** storing sessions in a database? That is also my goal. But if it is impossible to do it securely, I will scrap that bit. Also my point in using the user-agent was so that if an attacker got a cookie, at least they'd have to know exact browser configuration to use it

Comment: Also, for the cryptographic nonce, what if you wanted a "remember me" cookie that never expired?

Comment: @Earlz Without https you are vulnerable to firesheep style attacks and its an owasp violation.  Ideally you would use a session handler that would take all of this for you,  i know asp.net comes with one.  If for some reason you can't use the built in session handler then you could encrypt the cryptographic nonce stored in the database with a key stored in a file.  Then you should make sure you database is locked down.

Comment: @Earlz The cookie still needs to expire or its a CWE violation and there for a vulnerability.  Optionally the cookie value could be re-generated for the next request if it is past 24 hours from the issue date,  and it should still have another upper limit of maybe a week or a month.  I wouldn't make it much longer than that,  even that is uncomfortable because this value is susceptible to brute force.

Comment: @Earlz: I can only add one more thing to what Rook has already said: Your way of checking the user agent is not only useless because an attacker can easily change it but also because he can just use **his** user agent string when he computes the hash and not even know the real user's one. If you only verify if his hash is "correct" then it will be correct. Don't invent "home cooked authentication systems". If you want secure sessions without database lookups then read the Secure Cookie Protocol paper ([PDF](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~alexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf)).

Comment: @Zed I will read this paper, and also that measure is just to make stolen cookies that much less useful.